# Lighting web component UI testing with robotframework-selenium: Not able to interact with LWC element

Tags: lightning-web-components, test-automation, selenium, cumulusci

I am trying to automate a page with LWC, But due to shadow DOM, I am able to interact with element.

Is there a way where we can interact with the element.

[image]

Comment: Well, enabling encapsulation is one of the main purposes of shadow dom. Did you had a look [here](https://medium.com/rate-engineering/a-guide-to-working-with-shadow-dom-using-selenium-b124992559f).